# How to upload an image using dropzone.js and hapi.js

Tags: node.js, http-headers, cors, dropzone.js, hapi.js

Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/cmrust/hapi-dropzone), I am trying to upload image files to my hapi.js server. I am being hit with this error:

> CORS error: Some headers are not allowed

Here is my client setup (this is a react.js web client running on localhost:3000)

```
$('#upload')['dropzone']({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/sector/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Cache-Control': null, //required for cors
        'X-Requested-With': null, //required for cors,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'                
    }
})
```

And here is my route on the server side (running on localhost:8000):

```
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/api/sector/upload',
            config:{
                cors: true,
                payload:{
                    output: 'stream',
                    parse: true,
                    allow: 'multipart/form-data',
                    maxBytes: 268435456
                }
            },
            handler: function(request, reply) {
               ....
            }
```

How can I enable cors in this scenario? Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I used this hapi.js plugin [hapi-cors-headers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-cors-headers) and it solved my issue (for one facing the same issue)